# How do i fix "No module named storages.backends.s3boto" error with heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I am working with Amazon S3 to serve static files and also using heroku as a Paas. I following this [tutorial](http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/07/14/using-amazon-s3-to-host-your-django-static-files/). I did a,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

locally and it worked just fine but when i do a,

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

i get the error,

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing storage module storages.backends.s3boto: "No module named storages.backends.s3boto"
```

What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: did you install (requirements.txt) the correct library?

Comment: yes i did, infact i did a `pip freeze requirements.txt`. it works for me

Comment: is there `django-storages` in the requirements?

Comment: @EsseTi you my friend are genius, thats what was missing, apparently ma small brains thought if i did `pip freeze requirements.txt` it would add libraries that are not there. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome. i'll write an answer so you can mark it as accepted and people will not try to answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django storages: Import Error - no module named storages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207192/django-storages-import-error-no-module-named-storages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the `django-storages` is missing.
do a new `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks ... Even if your answer is a little older :)