# Django storages: Import Error - no module named storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, python-django-storages

I'm trying to use Django's storages backend (for BotoS3)

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'storages',
...
)
```

as shown in http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html.

and, requirements.txt:

```
django-storages==1.1.8
```

But am getting the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError storages: No module named storages
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed `django-storages` using `pip install` before or after adding it to the requirements file?

Comment: i had installed it before adding it to re.txt. But I just did a pip install again, and still get the same issue. Does the order make a difference, and if so how so?

Comment: No the order is immaterial, I was just making sure you had actually installed it. Are you in a virtualenv and installing it and running it in after activating the virtualenv?

Comment: d'oh, i'm an idiot! Yep, installing it in virtualenv resolved the issue. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: We have all been there ;)

Comment: I am getting the "ImportError: No module named storages" after pip installing django-storages in my virtual environment and updating requirements.txt
I get the error when running `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a possibility that you are in a virtualenv and installing the package outside the virtualenv into the default python installation. Make sure you are not doing that.

Comment: Please include context on how to "Make sure you are not doing that".

Answer (score 13):

If you are experiencing this error even though you've included `'storages'` in your `INSTALLLED_APPS` and `django-storages` in your `requirements.txt`, check your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` variable.

For previous versions of `django-storages`, this should be set as:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

For newer versions of `django-storages`, the package uses `boto3` instead of `boto` and this variable should be set as:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

If you're using either version and you've configured your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` setting incorrectly, you'll receive an import error.

The correct settings can be found in the [django-storages docs](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#migrating-from-boto-to-boto3)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.
In my case I solved the problem with

```
pip install django-storages

Collecting django-storages
  Downloading django_storages-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 358kB/s
Installing collected packages: django-storages
Successfully installed django-storages-1.6.5
```

It was executed inside my virtual environment.

Answer (score 3):

I had installed it within virtual env and was running the exact same issue. My problem was that I forgot to update my requirements.txt. So make you update that file!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pipenv make sure you install django-storages using

> pipenv install django-storages

so that the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock are both updated.

I had installed using pip inside the virtualenv and requirements.txt was updated but still receiving this error. After digging around I noticed it was not added to the Pipfile. I ran the installer and it cleared up the error.

Answer (score 1):

I installed with:
pip install -U django-storages

If you go to `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/storages/backends` you will see no file named `S3Boto` but `S3Boto3`.  I dropped in an old S3Boto file from an old virtual environment and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I was using virtual environment and installed django-storage as well as boto3 . But still I was getting these errors.

Initially I installed the packages using this command

```sh
pip install django-storages, boto3
```

This command solved my Issue

```sh
pip install -U django-storages
pip install -U boto3
```

- ***It updates the packages***

Answer (score 0):

EDX only if you are in local then run this command

```
paver update_assets --theme-dirs=/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/theme-name/
```