Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages' despite package being installed
I'm encountering a persistent ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run my Django project, even though the package is installed. Here are the details:
Problem
When I run:
python3 manage.py runserver
I get the following error:
CopyModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'
Environment:
Windows 10
Python 3.10
Django (version unspecified)
Virtual environment (houseVenv)

What I've tried:
1 - I've confirmed that django-storages is installed:
(houseVenv) PS C:\path\to\project> pip3 list | findstr storage
django-storages   1.14.4

However, when I try to import it manually, it fails:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'

2 - I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling django-storages.
3 - I've verified that I'm in the correct virtual environment.
4 - I've checked that 'storages' is in my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.
Why is Python unable to find the 'storages' module even though it's installed, and how can I resolve this issue?

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208036/10951070?  Also, can you share your settings.py.

However, when I try to import it manually, it fails Please show us the exact command you used to run this example.

What exactly should I share my "settings.py" file?
I can't post my entire file here.

I'm going to guess that you have two different installations of python on your computer, and the python3 and pip3 commands are each using a different one.

Show us the output of this command pip3 show django-storages and this command python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

Command: pip3 show django-storages
Result:
Name: django-storages
Version: 1.14.4
Summary: Support for many storage backends in Django
Home-page: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages
Author: 
Author-email: Josh Schneier <josh.schneier@gmail.com>
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\personalfiles\somelocation (not real)
Requires: Django
Required-by: 

Command: python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
Result: Part1
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0',

Result: Part 2:
'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
